# I want to write and read from file in order to display score in different html

Tags: javascript

I want to create snake game, everything works well, but I wish to pass score to another html file and I am unable. Is there any good way to transfer javascript variable into file from which i can then read? Or directly to another html would be best if possible. Thanks for every answer! I also wish to wait a little so person can see where he died but command "wait(function, miliseconds)" did not work.

I´ve already tryed this piece of code which resulted into nothing.

```
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
        set s  = fso.CreateTextFile("../pages/score.txt", True);
        s.writeline(score);
        s.Close();
```

My engame function right now:

```
function endGame() 
    {   
        clearInterval(game);
        clearInterval(spawnEnemy);
        clearInterval(spawnBonus);
        dead.play();
        window.location.href = "../pages/score.html";
    }
```

As wrote above I need to solve issue with file or displaying score in different html and also to wait before going into another page via window.location.href command.

Comment: you can not create text file from javascript

Comment: `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");` looks to me like ASP or [VB/C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object), not Javascript.

Comment: I am just begginer, this is my semestral project so I try everything I see, ok, lets say I already have file created, can I write that variable from that js file into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store variables in sessionStorage (is stored until the user closes the browser tab) or in localStorage (is stored without expiration date) and can access them from different sites then.

This is how you can store a value:

```
// store the score for future use
localStorage.setItem("score", 7);
```

This is how you can retrieve it:

```
// display the stored score
console.log("The stored score is: " + localStorage.getItem("score"));
```

You can trigger a function after a wait period like so:

```
//change this to the number of seconds you want to wait
var nrOfSeconds = 5;

//use the function you want to trigger after the wait period here
function theFunctionYouWantToTrigger(){
  console.log("Function was triggered after " + nrOfSeconds + " seconds");
}

//since the timeout needs the time in milliseconds we need to mulitply the seconds with 1000
window.setTimeout(theFunctionYouWantToTrigger, nrOfSeconds*1000);
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present. at endGame   I got this error with this line of code "localStorage.setItem(score);"

Comment: And then on other html page i get this error: score.html:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at score.html:8  with this line of code: <script>document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("score");</script>

Comment: You need to use localStorage.setItem("score", 7) if you want to set the score to 7 -> you are missing the quotation marks around score and you need to pass the number that should be stored

Comment: I updated my answer with a log output instead of an html content change. if you don't have an element with id "result" the code won't work you need to put it somewhere where you want to use it

Comment: Problem is that score is variable which snake scores, I mean how big was his tail. So it should look like this? localStorage.setItem("snakescore",score); ?

Comment: No I never used it before, we got 10 weeks to create games we picked and that´s it no help from teachers on these things... I never coded js before. I only did C,HTML,CSS,PHP so far..

Comment: Alright, so if you have document.getElementById("example") that means that javascript looks for an html element <div id="example"></div>
And if you use document.getElementById("example").innerHTML that will change the content of the html element -> so for example document.getElementById("example").innerHTML="test" would change it to:
<div id="example">test</div>
That makes sense?
You can also find really useful tips on w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp

Comment: Also thanks for that wait function I got it now working well, gotta look closer at that score variable now. Thanks for help so far :-). I will try on my own not to bother you anymore from what you provided to me thanks alot, take care!

Comment: I got it to work now :D yaaay thanks alot. All it needed was <div id="result"></div>

Comment: great :D glad I could help. Don't hesitate to ask if you have further questions :)